# BitLocker on Windows 7 Embedded Standard

Tags: bitlocker, windows-embedded-7

We’ve deployed a system with „Windows 7 Embedded Standard SP1“ which is strapped down regarding features but now should be updated to support BitLocker encryption. The .wim Image is updated to has the feature pack installed for **BitLocker secure StartUp / WinEmb-Security-SecureStartUp**  (configured with ICE).

But I’m unable to activate BitLocker (v6.1) with manage-bde or the UI because it’s always resulting in error code `0x8031005a` / „not supported“ and the BitLocker service always exits after 20 seconds.

I’ve read varying reports of the BitLocker support in Windows 7 Embedded unclear if this is not supported by license or by update/patch level.

Any ideas on how to activate BitLocker in this environment or if this error might be misleading to something else (like some not so obvious dependencies to other features)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, BL worked only on the enterprise and ultimate edition; else, it was not offered.